# How to use a subset of BMVert, BMEdges or BMFAces to construct a new "submesh" of an existing mesh?

Tags: python, mesh, geometry

**Hi everybody**,

thank you for reading the question.
For example, I have a complicated mesh. For some further analysis I like to create a submesh (i.e. a specific tangential plane) by a sublist of BMVert, BMEdges or BMFaces data structure elements.

**How can I create a mesh by elements of BMVert, BMEdges or BMFaces?**

There exists the function from_pydata, where you have to explicit specify the vertice coordinates and i.e the face references, but I did not find a similar function for BMVert, BMEdges or BMFaces lists.

I also found a function called bmesh.ops.dublicate, which gives me the error message: NotImplementedError: duplicate: keyword "dest" type 4 not working yet!

Another way I can think of would be to copy the mesh and delete all coplimentary BMFaces.

But I think there should exists a better way of creating a mesh by a sublist of BMVert, BMEdges or BMFaces data structure elements!!!

Do you have a hint?